# Unable to parse unstructured text

Tags: antlr4

I have file of the form given below:

```
* this is an sdata comment
sdata:
  abcd sdata line1                         <<==1
  sdata line2                              <<==2
* this is an cdata comment
cdata :
   cdata line1                             <<==3
  xyz cdata line2                          <<==4
```

The words sdata & cdata are keywords (there are more such), comments start with a '*'. All other lines (marked 1,2,3 &4) shown are unstructured data which needs to be read in for processing later. The unstructured data lines itself may have the keywords in it, but should not be considered as such. Unlike what is shown above, the unstructured data can also be in the same line as where the keywords are shown. For example, it can be "sdata : unstructured data here".

**The parser I have used is :
**

```
parser grammar testparser;

options { tokenVocab=testlexer;}


prog : stmt* EOF;

stmt : sdata | cdata ;

sdata: SDATA COLON dtext* ;

cdata: CDATA COLON dtext*;

dtext: DTEXT;
```

**And lexer is:**

```
lexer grammar testlexer;

SDATA: S D A T A;
CDATA: C D A T A;
COLON: ':';
COMMTAG: '*';
NL: '\r'?'\n'->skip;
WS: [ \t\f]+ ->skip;

COMMENT: COMMTAG .*? '\r'?'\n' ->channel(HIDDEN);
DTEXT: ~('\r'|'\n')+ '\r'?'\n';


fragment A:('a'|'A');
fragment B:('b'|'B');
fragment C:('c'|'C');
fragment D:('d'|'D');
fragment E:('e'|'E');
fragment F:('f'|'F');
fragment G:('g'|'G');
fragment H:('h'|'H');
fragment I:('i'|'I');
fragment J:('j'|'J');
fragment K:('k'|'K');
fragment L:('l'|'L');
fragment M:('m'|'M');
fragment N:('n'|'N');
fragment O:('o'|'O');
fragment P:('p'|'P');
fragment Q:('q'|'Q');
fragment R:('r'|'R');
fragment S:('s'|'S');
fragment T:('t'|'T');
fragment U:('u'|'U');
fragment V:('v'|'V');
fragment W:('w'|'W');
fragment X:('x'|'X');
fragment Y:('y'|'Y');
fragment Z:('z'|'Z');
```

I get:
8:2 token recognition error at: 'xyz cdata line2'
2:0 mismatched input 'sdata:\r\n' expecting {, SDATA, CDATA}

I have tried various other combo of parser & lexer. But I am unable to parse this. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Three questions: 1) does the `:` also appear inside the unstructured data? 2) When the unstructured data is on its own line, does it always start with one or more spaces? 3) Do the keywords always start at the beginning of the line?

Comment: Thanks for the reply..1)Yes, it could be in the unstructured data. 2) It could start from the beginning of the line 3)Yes, always

Comment: So it could happen that a line of unstructured data starts with a keyword followed by a `:`. Then it's impossible to tell which is which.

Comment: "impossible to tell which is which" -> I meant from inside a lexer rule. That is why my answer below "fixes" this by determining in a parser rule if a keyword really is a keyword or part of `dtext`.

Answer (score 0):

Your input text is tokenized as follows:

```
9 tokens:
  1    COMMENT                        '* this is an sdata comment\n'
  2    DTEXT                          'sdata:\n'
  3    DTEXT                          '  abcd sdata line1\n'
  4    DTEXT                          '  sdata line2\n'
  5    COMMENT                        '* this is an cdata comment\n'
  6    DTEXT                          'cdata :\n'
  7    DTEXT                          '   cdata line1\n'
  8    DTEXT                          '  xyz cdata line2\n'
  9    EOF                            '<EOF>'
```

As you can see `DTEXT` it created too many times (or better said: more than you expect). This is just how ANTLR's lexer works: match as many characters as possible. In case 2 or more lexer rules match the same characters, let the one defined first "win".

All lines are matched by `~('\r'|'\n')+ '\r'?'\n'`, so almost all lines are `DTEXT`s. Only the comment lines are also matched by `COMMTAG .*? '\r'?'\n'`, which is placed *before* the `DTEXT` rule, so that becomes a `COMMENT`.

If you write your grammar like this:

```
prog    : stmt* EOF;
stmt    : sdata | cdata ;
sdata   : NL SDATA COLON dtext;
cdata   : NL CDATA COLON dtext;
dtext   : NL* atom (NL+ atom)* NL* ;
atom    : (DTEXT | SDATA | CDATA)+;

SDATA   : S D A T A;
CDATA   : C D A T A;
COLON   : ':';
NL      : '\r'? '\n';
WS      : [ \t\f]+ -> skip;
COMMENT : '*' ~[\r\n]* ->channel(HIDDEN);
DTEXT   : ~[*: \t\r\n\f]+;
```

then your input:

```
* this is an sdata comment
sdata:
  abcd sdata line1
  sdata line2
* this is an cdata comment
cdata : cdata
cdata line1
  xyz cdata line2
```

will be parsed like this:

[image]

Note that if your input starts with a keyword, you must manually prepend a line break. There is no other way around it<sup>*</sup>, given keywords + colons can also occur inside the unstructured data.

<sup>*</sup> without using target specific code inside your grammar, which is very bad practice

Comment: Thanks! this will work. The keywords with embedded unstructured data is well below other lines. So definitely it will have an NL before it